# Combinatorial Problem about putting foxes in a $n\times n$ table

Tags: combinatorics, logic, square-numbers

Let $n$ be an integer with $n\geq 2$.

$k$ foxes are put into $n \times n$ table, and each $1 \times 1$ square has at most $1$ fox. They are put in such a way that each $2 \times 2$ table has exactly $2$ foxes. For what values of $k$, in respect to $n$, could that happen?

My intuition told me it is done with induction, but then I realized that for even $n$ we split the table into $n^2/4$ squares that are each $2 \times 2$, so turns out $k=n^2/2$ for even $n$. Right now I'm trying to prove for odd $n$.

Comment: Please avoid subjective titles.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the minimum and maximum $k$ are the same for even $n$; the only value of $k$ possible is $$k = \frac{n^2}{2}$$

---

**Hint 1**: For odd $n$, use the fact that there are four $n-1 \times n-1$ squares in an $n \times n$ square, along with the fact that $n-1$ is even, to show that the minimum $k$ is $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

This corresponds to an arrangement of the foxes in a "striped" pattern (every other row is all foxes, with the start and end rows being empty).

Similarly, you can show that the maximum $k$ is $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

This also corresponds to an arrangement of the foxes in a "striped" pattern, but this time the start and end rows are foxes.

---

This is only a hint because it remains to show which values of $k$ that are strictly between the minimum and the maximum are possible. Two examples of possible values are

$$\frac{n^2-1}{2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{n^2+1}{2}$$

These correspond to "checkerboard" arrangements of foxes.

In order to find the total number of possible values of $k$ for odd $n$, notice that two foxes next to each other in the same row determine the placement of foxes in *both* of their columns. Similarly, two foxes next to each other in the same column determine the placement of foxes in *both* of their rows.

This will eliminate many arrangements. For example, it is impossible to have an arrangement in which there is a pair of foxes vertically adjacent and another pair of foxes horizontally adjacent.

Comment: For $n=3$ I can make $6$ foxes. Unfortunately your formula gives maximum $k = 5$.

Comment: You're right. I've fixed the formula.

Comment: I've just proved that n(n-1)/2 is possible and wrote out the proof and now im writing for n(n+1)/2. But stuck on how to move "up" from the lowest to the highest. Could you please show how it is done? Thanks!